# Strong parameters for nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following nested resources:

```
resources :sources do
  resource :category_pages
end
```

When I am in the form of category_pages, I have this:

```
<%= form_for [params[:source_id], @category_page], url: source_category_pages_path do |form| %>
 <%= render partial: 'form', locals: { form: form } %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to see how can I make sure that the source_id is in the params in my controller. I have tried with:

```
 def create
   @category_page = CategoryPage.new(category_page_params)
 end

 def category_page_params
   params.require(:category_page).permit(:name, :url, :source_id)
 end
```

But I keep getting back an error saying that 'source_id' can't be blank. How am I supposed to use Strong Parameters in this case?

I have also tried this:

```
 def category_page_params
   params.require(:category_page, :source_id).permit(:name, :url)
 end
```

Because the source_id is not inside the category_page params, but apparently require just accepts one argument. Params look actually like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...=", "category_page"=>{"name"=>"", "url"=>""}, "commit"=>"Add Category Page", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"category_pages", "source_id"=>"1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`:source_id` is not a part of `category_page_params` because it isn't passed with `category_page`. Try using this function:

```
def source_id_params
  params.require(:source_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
def safe_params
  safe_attributes = [
    category_pages_attributes:
    [
      :id, :name, :url, :_destroy
    ]
  ]
  params.require(:source).permit(*safe_attributes)
end
```